# Accessing GTLPlusActivity properties

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-plus

I have integrated the Google Plus iOS SDK v1.2.1 into my iOS app. After authentication I am trying to fetch the user's activity feed. My code is the following:

```
 GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
    [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];
    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForActivitiesListWithUserId:@"me" collection:kGTLPlusCollectionPublic];

    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusActivityFeed *data,
                                NSError *error) {

                for (GTLPlusActivity *activity in data.items) {

                    // ITERATE THROUGH THE ACTIVITIES

                    NSString *publishedDate = activity.published; <---- ERROR

                    // "PROPERTY 'published' CANNOT BE FOUND 
                    // IN FORWARD CLASS OBJECT "GTLPLusActivity""
                    // WHY ARE THE VARIABLES SUCH AS published, placeName, 
                    // title, actor etc NOT ACCESSIBLE
                }

            }];
```

I am able to successfully retrieve the posts of the user. The GTLPlusActivity class has many properties as shown in the image:

[image]

Whenever I try to access the properties using the "." operator such as "activity.actor" in the for loop, it gives the error `"Property 'actor' cannot be found in forward class object 'GTLPlusActivity'"`. Why am I unable to access the properties? I need to display them in a UITableView.

**EDIT:** Code Snapshot. Error clearly displayed in Red.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, check the error condition and make sure the error code is nil.  I have tried your code, and it works correctly on my end, so most likely, there is a problem with the response you are getting back.  Generally activity.actor will return a GTLPlusActivityActor.

Try something like:

`if (error) {
  NSLog(@"Status: Error: %@", error);
}
else
<Do stuff>`

EDIT: Also, our iOS quick-start is a great resource for seeing how we handle certain parts of the code.  The ListMoments bit is pretty similar to dealing with Activities.
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ios

EDIT 2: Also, make sure you have all of the right imports.  Try

```
#import "GTLPlusActivity.h"
```

or

```
#import "GTLPlus.h"
```

Comment: The problem is not that the I am not able to get the posts. I don't receive any error. The problem is that I am unable to access the "GTLPlusActivity" class properties. I am adding an edit to explain it better.

Comment: Edited the code box within the for loop in my question. As you can see, I am trying to access the published date for each activity. But it gives an error. It says the published property (and all others) of the class 'GTLPlusActivity' cannot be found even though the class declaration clearly lists all the properties.

Comment: Oh you are right, I hadn't imported the class. That fixed it. Thanks!